# How Does the Model Binder Work for an Action with Multiple Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I was looking at an Action in an ASP.NET MVC Controller that looked about like so:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction( SomeClass sc, OtherClass oc ) {

    if( ModelState.IsValid ) {

        ... // do things

    }

    return View();

}
```

And I began to wonder what exactly `ModelState.IsValid` is checking. In other words, given that there are multiple parameters, what is the model? Does it validate the fields in the first parameter, sc, or does it look at all of the fields in all parameters, or what?

It seems clear that one could create a wrapper class, such as

```
public class WholeModel {

    public SomeObject sc {get; set;}
    public OtherClass oc {get; set;}

}
```

and pass that in, in which case clearly that whole thing would be the model. But do we need to do that? Why or why not, and how does the model binder determine what needs to be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a test with these models:

```
public class SimpleFormModel {

    [Required]
    public Guid aGuid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String aString { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int anInt { get; set; }

    public SimpleFormModel( ) {
        this.aGuid = new Guid( "ABCD1234-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD1234EF56" );
        this.anInt = 42;
        this.aString = "The string from the base constructor.";
    }
}

public class AdditionalFormModel {
    [Required]
    public string aString2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int anInt2 { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller with this action:

```
public ActionResult MultipleParameters( SimpleFormModel modelOne, AdditionalFormModel modelTwo ) {
    if( !ModelState.IsValid ) {
        modelOne.aString = "The model isn't valid.";
    }

    return View(modelOne);
}
```

and also this View:

```
@model SimpleFormModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MultipleParameters";
}

<h2>MultipleParameters</h2>

<form action="/Home/MultipleParameters" method="post">

    <input name="aGuid" type="text" value="@Model.aGuid"/><br />
    <input name="anInt" type="text" value="@Model.anInt"/><br />
    <input name="aString" type="text" value="@Model.aString"/><br />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Update</button>

</form>
```

No matter what, the string shows up in the form as "The model isn't valid.", as I'm not providing the required properties for `AdditionalFormModel`. So, yes the model binder is checking the validity of both classes, even though the only indication that it has that an `AdditionalFormModel` should be included is that class's presence in the Action's parameter list.

If I remove the `[Required]` attributes from `AdditionalFormModel`'s properties, then the string is updated fine and the models are considered valid. Alternatively, I can provide an explicit parameterless constructor for `AdditionalFormModel` that initializes each required property, like in `SimpleFormModel`, and that works as well.

It would still be nice to see an answer with some insight into the process that results in this behavior, but this answers whether it checks both or not.

Comment: Your comment was a question, yes. The above is an incomplete answer, which explicitly indicates what is missing.

Comment: that anwer you posted just shows that you had no a clear idea of what your question was. thats why I told you to TRY IT, because thats how STACKOVERFLOW.COM works, you try, then you ask. have a read here http://stackoverflow.com/about , you will have better anwers in future.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure you're the one with no clear idea of what my question was. I have read that about page, and nothing there conflicts with this question or answer in any way. Your comments have not been useful, and are starting to become offensive. Please refrain from more unecessary comments. I did try it, but in a large project. After receiving no decent answers, I set up a controlled experiment and posted the results as a partial answer. If no one cares to explain, then at some point I'll accept my answer, even though it's incomplete.

Comment: I am just trying to help, the binder will check everithing, that's all you need to know, it will validate each class, even if they are nested, that's all, there no more to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

it will validate all parameters, even if they are nested clases.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: I dont get what I have to elaborate. just post some data to your server and find if it is working as you expect. in my experience I can tell you it will validate them

Comment: when you post data it validate classes, so all related classes in your post will be evaluated, even if you have a class that has an array of classes. it will validate each element in your array of classes.

Comment: What is one of the things is an int passed in via the url? That doesn't seem to be working for me. It's not validating the model